# Add HTML to Page Title for Entity (Profile2)

Tags: theming, entities, users, display-suite

I have a Profile2 page where I want to add some HTML into the page title (I want to insert a fontawesome icon). I am using Display Suite to layout the Profile2 page with a custom view mode.

I have succeeded in over-writing the title using the function hook_profile2_view_alter() and drupal_set_title(), but drupal_set_title() uses check_plain, which strips out all the extra html. I tried using hook_preprocess_page, but there is no title variable available. I think this is because Display Suite takes over the title variable, and renames it as label. I also tried the [html_title](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title) module without any luck, as I'm pretty sure this is because it only works on nodes and not on entities. I also tried hook_preprocesss_profile2 (having first used mymodule_preprocess_entity(&$variables, $hook) to create the function suggestion), but this function doesn't seem to be running on the page. I'm not sure if this is because I'm using display suite or a custom view mode.

Any help much appreciated, as I seem to be running out of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the HTML to a custom page template based on the user role and profile. I used the following code to create the template suggestion in the template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;    
    if(arg(0) == 'profile-carer' && in_array('my custom role', $user->roles)) :
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__profile_carer_my_custom_role';
    endif;
}
```

I was then able to use the custom template `page--profile-carer-my-custom-role.tpl.php` based on the page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

I have also since found another method explained at [Display Suite and HTML node titles](https://web.archive.org/web/20140125200758/http://thislittleduck.com/content/display-suite-and-html-node-titles)